# sql query that selects the newest 100 articles then returns 30 articles of that result by top rated ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

I am asking for a query that selects the newest 100 articles, then returns 30 articles of that result by top rated ordering. Something is wrong in my example.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
     SELECT articleid,articletitle,articleicon,timesviewed 
     FROM articles 
     WHERE articlestatus = 1 AND (articletype = 1 || articletype = 6) 
     ORDER BY articleid DESC LIMIT 100
) 
ORDER BY (totalvotepoints/totalvotes) DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Make the horizontal scroll bar go away and I'll read the entire thing.

Comment: @DanBracuk Wish granted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. The inner SELECT query needs to include the `totalvotepoints` and `totalvotes` columns (or even just the result of the division operation).
2. The inner query needs a name, even though the name is never used. I'm more of a sql server guy, so maybe mysql lets you get away with this, but I'd expect the query to fail without a name supplied after the sub query

Put it all together:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT articleid,articletitle,articleicon,timesviewed,totalvotepoints/totalvotes As rating
    FROM articles 
    WHERE articlestatus = 1 AND articletype IN (1,6) 
    ORDER BY articleid DESC LIMIT 100
) t
ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 30
```

Also as a Sql Server guy I was surprised to find that the result of dividing two integers is a floating-point type, instead of an integer division. Most systems will do integer division here unless you specifically cast one side to a floating point type, if for no other reason than that sometimes you *need* integer division. It seems that in MySql, the only way to do integer division is with the `DIV` operator, which is a non-standard extension to ansi sql.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `SELECT` statement does not include the columns `totalvotepoints` and `totalvotes`. Therefore the outer `SELECT` cannot reference them. Try

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT articleid,articletitle,articleicon,timesviewed,totalvotepoints,totalvotes
FROM articles 
WHERE articlestatus = 1 AND articletype IN (1,6) 
ORDER BY articleid DESC 
LIMIT 100
) 
ORDER BY (totalvotepoints/totalvotes) 
DESC LIMIT 30
```